# Get org link to insert link description automatically?

Tags: org-mode, elisp

**Q:** How can I get a custom `org` link function to insert a description automatically?

I'd like to store `org` links to files in a `dired` buffer, but would prefer that the link description be the file name sans path rather than report the full path, ie:

```
file:~/the/full/path/myfile.ext     ; default, but no thanks
myfile.ext                          ; what I want
```

Now: `org-store-link` hardcodes links from `dired` to provide the default.  Instead, I've written a custom function (cribbing from the hard-coded function) and added it to `org-store-link-functions`:

```
(defun dired-store-link ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
    (let ((file (dired-get-filename nil t)))
      (setf file (if file
                     (abbreviate-file-name (expand-file-name file))
                   default-directory))
      (org-store-link-props :type        "dired"
                            :link        file
                            :description (file-name-nondirectory file))
      file)))

(add-to-list 'org-store-link-functions #'dired-store-link)
```

So far so good, and it works as expected, but for one thing:

- When calling `org-insert-link` with the built-in, default behavior, it simply inserts the link without asking me for a description.
- When calling `org-insert-link` with my custom function, it prompts me to enter a description (which it correctly populates with the file name stored in the `:description` property).

I'd rather not be prompted for the description each time, and want `org-insert-link` to use the value of `:description` that the custom function sets.

*How can I convince `org-insert-link` to use the `:description` automatically without prompting me for it?*

Comment: Do the optional arguments `link-location` or `default-description` in the function `org-insert-link` help any?  *If the LINK-LOCATION parameter is non-nil, this value will be used as the link location instead of reading one interactively.  If the DEFAULT-DESCRIPTION parameter is non-nil, this value will be used as the default description.*

Comment: @lawlist: thanks for the suggestion, although I'm not sure how I'd set it in interactive use without wrapping it in another function.  However, it made me read the docstring more closely, which got me to an answer of sorts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buried at the bottom of the docstring for `org-insert-link` is a note that:

> If `org-make-link-description-function` is non-nil, this function will be
>   called with the link target, and the result will be the default
>   link description.

Apparently `org` throws away a lot of information in the process of storing a link, so all that's left in `org-stored-links` is a list of entries of the form `(link description)`.  Insofar as the earlier function has a file name for the link, it looks like the following works:

```el
(defun org-link-describe (link desc)
  (if (file-exists-p link)
      desc
    (read-string "Description: " desc)))

(setf org-make-link-description-function #'org-link-describe)
```

It's kind of hacky, and I haven't tested it extensively, but it seems to work so far.  Would be thrilled to see a more elegant solution, of course.

Comment: Now that you know this function, can't you ditch `dired-store-link` and just use this to create the description you want? I think that would end up a lot shorter.

Comment: @Malabarba: you're probably right -- this function could be rewritten to inspect the link for a file and proceed accordingly.  Will try it out when I get a spare moment.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using org 9.1.6, and to my dismay it seems that `org-store-link-functions` is now a builtin org function (rather than a hook), so the original solution no longer works. There may be a workaround using `org-link-parameters`, but instead I'm using the following little hack, which seems to do the trick:

```lisp
(defun my//dired-store-link (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
      (let ((file (dired-get-filename nil t)))
        (setf file (if file
                       (abbreviate-file-name (expand-file-name file))
                     default-directory))
        (let ((link (concat "file:" file))
              (desc (file-name-nondirectory file)))
          (push (list link desc) org-stored-links)
          (car org-stored-links)))
    (apply orig-fun args)))
(advice-add 'org-store-link :around #'my//dired-store-link)
```

As a bonus, this does not prompt for a description, since the description pushed to `org-stored-links` is non-nil.