# How to use the headline numbering for links in org-num-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-link

I use org-num-mode to have headlines with a numbering 1.1.1 or 1.2.1... etc

When I use org-insert-link, I want the default description to be this number. For now, it is the text in the headline but I would much prefer the number to be the default setting.

I think if I can get the numbering for a given headline I should be able to cook up something using [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13093/get-org-link-to-insert-link-description-automatically) but I did not find how to get the current headline's numbering.

EDIT: as indicated in the comments, for this to work I must most likely use an export hook to get the section numbers at export time.

Comment: What happens if you introduce another headline between two of the old headlines? I presume that the numbers change but the links wouldn't. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: You are right I would not want that. Maybe a post-processing like org-export-before-parsing would do the trick. I guess the link would have dummy names that are then replaces in the org-export-before-parsing hook. I am a bit new to elisp but I think this should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `org-num--make-overlay` we find that `org-nume-mode` does not insert extra contents in a buffer, but only creates the numbers as overlays (via the 'after-string' property). So, to get the numbers, you should get the appropriate property of that overlay. The following function provides an example for how to achieve what you want:

```lisp
(defun org-replace-links-descs (&rest _) ; accepts, any number of 'unused'; arguments
  (interactive)
  (if (not org-num-mode)
      (message "org-num-mode not active")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (stringp (org-next-link)))
      (let* ((context (org-element-context))
             (beg (org-element-property :begin context))
             (end (org-element-property :end context))
             (cbeg (org-element-property :contents-begin context))
             (cend (org-element-property :contents-end context))
             (raw-link (org-element-property :raw-link context))
             file
             num)
        (when (string-match  "\\(^*\\|:\\*\\)" raw-link)
          (save-excursion
            (org-link-open context)
            (unless org-num-mode (org-num-mode))
            (skip-chars-forward "*")
            ;; there can be multiple overlays so we filter out 'org-num' overlay
            (when (string-match "^file" raw-link)
              (setq file (nth 1 (split-string raw-link ":"))))
            (setq num (substring
                       (car
                        (delete nil
                                (mapcar (lambda (o)
                                          (when (overlay-get o 'org-num)
                                            (overlay-get o 'after-string)))
                                        (overlays-at (point)))))
                       0 -1)))
          (let ((new-desc (concat file (when file ":") num)))
            (if cbeg
                (replace-region-contents cbeg cend (lambda () new-desc))
              (goto-char (1- end))
              (insert "[" new-desc "]"))))))))

(defun my-org-export-dispatch ()
  (interactive)
  (when org-num-mode
    (org-replace-links-descs))
 (org-export-dispatch))
```

Now, you can call the `org-replace-links-descs` function 'manually' before export, or you can create a custom function, where you call `org-replace-links-descs` before you export function, like in the `my-org-export-dispatch` example, to 'trigger' the export (another option would be to advise the export function, but if using a 'custom export function' is an option, then that would be the easiest solution).

Comment: I tried to add this to the export using `(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook #'org-replace-links-descs)` but it did not work. Could you explain more what this function do ? How can I use it (i.e. will it change the description of any link I do ? How must I do the link in order for it to be recognized by your code ? ).

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you can call the function 'manually', i.e. via `M-x`, before export. There are two reasons why the function does not work in the hook. First, as mentioned in the hook's docstring, the hook passes a single argument when calling each function. Second, the function in the hook is executed in a copy of the original buffer where `org-num-mode` is not active. Therefore, you should execute the function in the original buffer before export. I have updated the answer.

Comment: To answer your other two questions, it should work on any link in your buffer, as long as you have inserted it using (the format as inserted by) `org-insert-link`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tested and it does not work: it replaces the description with the number of the section in which the link is currently, it does not replace the description with the number from the target of the link.

Comment: Isn't that what you asked: "When I use org-insert-link, I want the default description to be this number?" Please explain more clearly what you mean. Do you mean that you use `org-insert-link` to create links to headlines? You did not write anything about 'target of a link' in your question. And I am still not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: Okay, I guess you mean that you want this number when you use `org-store-link`. As I never use 'org-store/insert-link', that was not clear to me.

Comment: When I use `org-insert-link`, I make a link that points to some header. Typically the link will look like this: `[[* Header 1][description]]` and yes I do this with `org-insert-link`. The goal is that in the end, I see the name of the target of the link (i.e. the number for `Header 1` here) in the description of the link (and the link is often in another header), because it would make things more readable. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Thanks, no problem, I had concluded that by now indeed :) The behavior you explain makes more sense of course, but I was not very familiar with using org-store-link. I have updated the code to do what you asked. As far as I understood from your question, you would like the description to 'contain' the number of the target link only (so that is what the code does).

Comment: For completeness, I've added support for links to headers in 'external' org files (if interested, you can check the edit history to see the changes).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work for me.